# How to split text scraped from a website?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

On the website I am trying to scrape, all the information is under the same class `.panel-row-text`. I am unsure how I can split this info so that it is just displayed under the relevant title, as right now each line will show all of the data.

```
    const axios = require('axios');
    const cheerio = require('cheerio');

    const url = 'https://www.lseg.com/resources/1000-companies-inspire/2018-report-1000-companies-uk/search-1000-companies-uk-2018?results_per_page=100';

    axios(url)
      .then(response => {
        const html = response.data;
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const dataTable = $('.tabular-data-panel > ul');
        const companyData= [];        
        //console.log(dataTable.length);

        dataTable.each(function(){
            const companyName = $(this).find('.panel-row-text').text();
            const website = $(this).find('.panel-row-text').text();
            const sector = $(this).find('.panel-row-text').text();
            const region = $(this).find('.panel-row-text').text();
            const revenueBand = $(this).find('.panel-row-text').text();

            companyData.push({
                companyName,
                website,
                sector,
                region,
                revenueBand,
            });

        });

        console.log(companyData);

      })
      .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be smart on how to query the labels associated by each field. You can simply query the labels first and then use the `.next()` function to get the value of the associated label.

> Note: I added an extra package named, **camelcase**, to make the queried labels/properties easier to read.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const camelCase = require('camelcase'); // added this to make properties readable

// use async / await feature
async function scrape(url) {

    // get html page
    const { data } = await axios.get(url);

    // convert html string to cheerio instance
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);

    // query all list items
    return $('.tabular-data-panel > ul')
        // convert cheerio collection to array for easier manipulation
        .toArray()
        // transform each item into proper key values
        .map(list => $(list)
            // query the label element
            .find('.panel-row-title')
            // convert to array for easier manipulation
            .toArray()
            // use reduce to create the object
            .reduce((fields, labelElement) => {
                // get the cheerio instance of the element
                const $labelElement = $(labelElement);
                // get the label of the field
                const key = $labelElement.text().trim();
                // get the value of the field
                const value = $labelElement.next().text().trim();
                // asign the key value into the reduced object
                // note that we used camelCase() to make the property easy to read
                fields[camelCase(key)] = value;
                // return the object
                return fields;
            }, {})
        );


}

async function main() {
    const url = 'https://www.lseg.com/resources/1000-companies-inspire/2018-report-1000-companies-uk/search-1000-companies-uk-2018?results_per_page=100';
    const companies = await scrape(url);
    console.log(companies);
}

main();
```

Comment: if there are child element in panel-row-text containtet div may happens that .Try to .If so try to get the text of chield element innertext

Comment: @LDS there are no such cases in the url that the OP has been scraping. Besides, `innerText` property does not exist in cheerio nodes. Additionally, `text()` removes all the tags and only retains the text portion of the element and child elements.